# Took more time to initiate CI job when GitLab merge request created

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci, git-webhooks

- I am using the Gitlab version of GitLab Community Edition 10.3.5.
- For Gitlab integration with CI, I have written the Gitlab webhook and using it for CI using Jenkins.
- While creating a new merge request in Gitlab, it's taking more time to initiate the Jenkins job nowadays.
- While test the webhook in Gitlab, its executed successfully and also got the success message as below. 
  Hook executed successfully: HTTP 200
- But, we are not getting post data values from the configured webhook in Gitlab project quickly and it's taking much time to update the post data values
- Due to this, Jenkin's job took more time to initiate and run.
- Note that there is no issue with Jenkins and Gitlab server access. It is very fast and active. Job initiating in Jenkins and delay in delivering the post data values to the webhook when MR created making the problem. How to resolve this?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.